# Safari error in Intranet Http & Https

Tags: safari, http

If I access my company's intranet using the https URL on Safari, the multiple login request doesn't happen (One time login only).

But, the multiple login request happens when I use the http URL.

Why is there a difference between this both protocol for the same site? What would be the reason apart from different port number?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about what you are consider as multiple login.

Anyway, the difference between the two protocol is that: `HTTPS` is the standard `HTTP` with additional `S` a secure layer. This additional layer is used to perform an encrypted connection and so the link is more secure. The main motivation for HTTPS is authentication of the visited website and protection of the privacy and integrity of the exchanged data.

The difference in your intranet company is that with `HTTPS` you don't need to verified the login multiple time because you are already secure (the server already know you), while from the `HTTP` you have no encryption and so every time you must autenticate yourself.